# Use BroadcastReceiver in Fragment in ViewPager

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-broadcastreceiver

I am trying to make a Music Player App for Android following this tutorial:
https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-music-player-on-android-project-setup--mobile-22764

I've changed the code so the SongList (List containing all songs found on the device) is in a Fragment now. I've used an Intent sent with LocalBroadcastManager when the MusicService's onCreate() method is called. I added a BroadcastReceiver in the SongListFragment. The intent contains the MusicService itself, so it can be called by the Fragment (e.g. for playing a song, when the user picks one).  It worked fine, till I added a ViewPager to the MainActivity (the SongListFragment is one of the fragments inside the ViewPager). 
The App is starting normally and the MusicService sends the intent, but the BroadcastReceiver's onReceive() is never running.

Here is the code for the MusicService:

```
public class MusicService extends Service implements
     MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener, MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener, Serializable{

public MediaPlayer player;
private ArrayList<Song> songs;
private int songPosn;
private ArrayList<String> playlist = new ArrayList<String>();
private long currSong=0; //currently playing song id, default==0
private NotificationService notificationService;

private String songTitle="";
private static final int NOTIFY_ID=1;
private static final String LOG_TAG = MusicService.class.getSimpleName();

private boolean shuffle=false;

private AudioManager audioManager;

private IBinder musicBind = new MusicBinder();

public void onCreate(){
    super.onCreate();
    songPosn=0;

    Intent intent = new Intent(Constants.ACTION.BIND_FRAG_ACTION);
    intent.putExtra(Constants.ACTION.MUSIC_SERVICE_EXTRA, this);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
    Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Intent with musicService Extra sent.=============");

    player = new MediaPlayer();
    initMusicPlayer();
    Random rand = new Random();
    audioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
}
```

and the SongListFragment:

```
public class SongListFragment extends Fragment implements MediaController.MediaPlayerControl, AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

private ArrayList<String> orderedSongsId = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<Song> songList;
private MusicService musicService;
private NotificationService notificationService;
private Menu menu;

private View rootView;
private ListView songListView;

private boolean musicBound = false;
private MusicController controller;
private boolean paused = false, playbackPaused = false;

private static final String LOG_TAG = SongListFragment.class.getSimpleName();
private static final String TAG = SongListFragment.class.getSimpleName();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);   

LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this.getActivity().getApplicationContext()).registerReceiver(mMusicServiceReceiver,
            new IntentFilter(Constants.ACTION.BIND_FRAG_ACTION)); 
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.songs_list_fragment, container, false);
    Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Fragment view is created ------------------------------");
    songList = new ArrayList<Song>();
    getSongList();
    Collections.sort(songList, new Comparator<Song>() {
        public int compare(Song a, Song b) {
            return a.getTitle().compareTo(b.getTitle());
        }
    });
    for (int i = 0; i < songList.size(); i++) {
        orderedSongsId.add(String.valueOf(songList.get(i).getId()));
    }

    SongAdapter adapter = new SongAdapter(getActivity(), songList);
    songListView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.song_list);
    songListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    songListView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    if (controller == null)setController();
    return rootView;
}

private BroadcastReceiver mMusicServiceReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        MusicService ms = (MusicService) intent.getSerializableExtra(Constants.ACTION.MUSIC_SERVICE_EXTRA);
        if (ms != null) Log.v(LOG_TAG, "MusicService received-------------------------------");
        else Log.v(LOG_TAG, "MusicService not received----------------------------");
        musicService = ms;
        musicService.setList(songList);
    }
};
```

I think the problem is the line
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this.getActivity().getApplicationContext())...
in the Fragments OnCreate(). Do I need to change the context there?

Comment: use getActivity() insted of this.getActivity()

Comment: you can also use event Bus library to solve your issue.